# calculate distance travelled by body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Body moves in coordinates $(x,y)= (a\sin\omega t,a(1-\cos\omega t))$, calculate distance travelled by the body after time $t$. (a, $\omega$ are constanst > 0 )

In my solution at first glance i thought about some curvelinear integrals, but i have no idea how to write one, simply wirting 
$$
\int x(t)dt
$$
gives nothing what would make sense. Then i tried to work with the length of the curve 
$$
\int \sqrt{1+(x'(t))^2}
$$
but still it leads nowhere, and i dont know how to use $y(t)$. I tried to figure out the similiar problem with polar coordinates, but i can give an answer because of intuittion, not integrals.

It seems that my understanding is not as deep as i wish it to be.

This task is not a homework, a friend of mine asked me to him help with this (it is his homework) and I would love to help, but right now i dont see a solution.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Is $x'=dx/dt$ or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is homework, I'll leave some of the computing to your friend.

With:
$$x(t)=a\sin\omega t$$
$$y(t)=a(1-\cos\omega t)$$
Compute:
$$v_x=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$
$$v_y=\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$
Then:
$$v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$$
The distance $d\ell$ travelled in an infinitesimal interval $dt$ is given by:
$$v=\frac{d\ell}{dt}$$
$$\implies d\ell=vdt$$
Integrate:
$$\int_0^{\ell}d\ell=\int_0^tvdt$$
$$\ell=\int_0^tvdt$$